# Graphql query into SQL query using join-monster

Tags: javascript, postgresql, graphql, knex.js

I used join-monster to convert graphql query into SQL query to fetch date from postgres. I have implemented a small example with the help of join-monster docs to achieve it. But when i try to run the graphql query I get error '"Must call joinMonster in a resolver on a field where the type is decorated with "sqlTable"."'

Can someone please point out what exactly i am missing. Below is my schema.js code

```
 const graphql = require('graphql');
 var _ = require('lodash');
 const { Client } = require('pg');
 const joinMonster = require('join-monster').default;
 const knex = require('knex');





const client = new Client({
user: 'postgres',
host: 'l662.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
database: 'graphqldb',
password: 'Password01',
port: 5432,
 });

 client.connect();

 var q = "SELECT * FROM graphql_user_details";

client.query(q, function(err, results){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("results are",results);
  client.end();
 });


 const {
   GraphQLObjectType,
   GraphQLID,
   GraphQLString,
   GraphQLInt,
   GraphQLList,
   GraphQLSchema

    } = graphql


    const User = new GraphQLObjectType({
     name: 'User',
     sqlTable: 'graphql_user_details',
     uniqueKey: 'id',
     fields: () => ({
     id: {
     type: GraphQLInt
   },
   name: {
     description: 'A user\'s first and last name',
     type: GraphQLString,
    extensions: {
      joinMonster: {
      // if the column name is different, it must be specified
      sqlColumn: 'name'
     }
   }
  },
   age: {
     description: 'A user\'s age',
     type: GraphQLInt,
     extensions: {
    joinMonster: {
      // if the column name is different, it must be specified
      sqlColumn: 'age'
      }
     }
   }
  })
   })



 const QueryRoot = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',

   fields: () => ({
     user: {
     type: User,
     args: {id:{type: GraphQLInt}},
      // how to write the WHERE condition
      where: (usersTable, args, context) => {
      if (args.id) return `${usersTable}.id = ${args.id}`
      },
     resolve: (parent, args, context, resolveInfo) => {
    
    return joinMonster(resolveInfo, {}, sql => {
      // knex is a query library for SQL databases
      return knex.raw(sql)
      })
     }
    }
   })
  })

  module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
   query: QueryRoot
  })
```

Comment: I don't think passing `sqlTable` and `uniqueKey` as config to `new GraphQLObjectType` is valid.

Comment: This is what they have given in the join-monster example. I am not sure where else I need to add sqltable